# Should/Could this "recursive Task" be expressed as a TaskContinuation?

Tags: c#, recursion, task-parallel-library

In my application I have the need to continually process some piece(s) of `Work` on some set interval(s). I had originally written a `Task` to continually check a given `Task.Delay` to see if it was completed, if so the `Work` would be processed that corresponded to that `Task.Delay`. The draw back to this method is the `Task` that checks these `Task.Delays` would be in a psuedo-infinite loop when no `Task.Delay` is completed.

To solve this problem I found that I could create a "recursive `Task`" (I am not sure what the jargon for this would be) that processes the work at the given interval as needed.

```
// New Recurring Work can be added by simply creating 
// the Task below and adding an entry into this Dictionary.
// Recurring Work can be removed/stopped by looking 
// it up in this Dictionary and calling its CTS.Cancel method.
private readonly object _LockRecurWork = new object();
private Dictionary<Work, Tuple<Task, CancellationTokenSource> RecurringWork { get; set; }
...
private Task CreateRecurringWorkTask(Work workToDo, CancellationTokenSource taskTokenSource)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // Do the Work, then wait the prescribed amount of time before doing it again
        DoWork(workToDo);
        await Task.Delay(workToDo.RecurRate, taskTokenSource.Token);

        // If this Work's CancellationTokenSource is not
        // cancelled then "schedule" the next Work execution
        if (!taskTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            lock(_LockRecurWork)
            {
                RecurringWork[workToDo] = new Tuple<Task, CancellationTokenSource>
                    (CreateRecurringWorkTask(workToDo, taskTokenSource), taskTokenSource);
            }
        }
    }, taskTokenSource.Token);
}
```

**Should/Could this be represented with a chain of `Task.ContinueWith`?** *Would there be any benefit to such an implementation? Is there anything majorly wrong with the current implementation?*

Comment: You should probably use a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: Your "recurring task" is just a less-efficient version `await` in a loop.  (but don't do that in the first place)

Comment: @KDecker: No, you should use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**!

Calling `ContinueWith` tells the `Task` to call your code as soon as it finishes.  This is *far* faster than manually polling it.

Comment: By manually polling do you mean my use of `await Task.Delay`? // Would it make more sense, with continuations, to alternate between types of `Task` for instance,`DoWorkTask.ContinueWith(Task.Delay).ContinueWith(DoWorkTask....`? Instead of awaiting within a single `Task`?

Comment: No; I mean get rid your entire function & delays and work with the original task directly  (your actual goal is not clear).