# C# Best way to schedule recurring task in an efficient windows service

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf

I write a Windows Service in .Net Framework 4.0 and I need to schedule a recurring task inside. New task can only run if previous one is finished, so no tasks in parallel...
All my task occurences work on same object (WCF Channel factory).
A task takes almost 2 seconds to complete and may be scheduled every 2 seconds or every hour.
My constraint is to have this Windows service as invisible/light as possible on memory and processor uses point of view...

I've already found these 2 ways:

- Use a `System.Timers.Timer` with `Autoreset` to false => I've to
  implement an `ElapsedEventHandler` and pass my shared object (WCF
  Channel factory)
- Use a never ending loop: not sure of mem/proc use in
  that state but no threads aspect to take care of.

Any suggestions?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Here is a way I implemented recurring tasks using the TPL. It might give you another idea/route. http://stackoverflow.com/q/39457595/2985796

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me was fine following: I'm started timer once, then in Tick method I will schedule next Tick call. Like this:

```
private Timer _timer;

//Interval in milliseconds
int _interval = 1000;

public void SetTimer()
{   
    // this is System.Threading.Timer, of course
    _timer = new Timer(Tick, null, _interval, Timeout.Infinite);
}

private void Tick(object state)
{
    try
    {
        // Put your code in here
    }   
    finally
    {
        _timer?.Change(_interval, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}

// dont forget to dispose your timer using await _timer.DisposeAsync(); or _timer.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks Tym, I suppose that I should have new System.Threading.Timer(Tick, MyWCFSharedObject, _interval, Timeout.Infinite) in my case... If ok, I hope that all changes made to my MyWCFSharedObject inside Tick method will be visible at Windows Service level?

Comment: Tick - just function, you can make it visible on aly level, you can event able to make it public static, if you really need this.

Comment: actually, as sample where I used this, https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/develop/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.BEServerModule/BEServiceLogic.cs#L108

Comment: Ok, got it Tym! Thanks! I try your solution and go back to validate this answer.

Comment: @Francois nope. It is not possible to have Tick runned in different threads simultaneously in my solution.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. :) I try now to Schedule next task every hour exactly. Not sure it's really possible with this solution...

Comment: Depends of your requirements. If you allow parallel tasks, so just timer, if not, so interlocked (or you can calculate time to next tick from previous manually in my solution)

Answer (score 1):

`System.Timers.Timer` is the way to go and will have little to no system performance impact. Current systems can handle thousands of timers.

Since you want the timer to continue, don't set AutoReset, but you will need a way to change its interval (if that's what you need).

Your service instance should hold an instance of your WCF channel factory.

To ensure synchronous processing, you should implement an `Interlocked` protected flag, like a long, which can serve as an indicator of busyness. If equal to one, for example, the method that kicks off processing from timer elapsed event will simply return. Once processing is complete, at which time you set the flag to zero, further timer elapsed events will be able to enter and kick off processing again.

Remember to stop, restart, and dispose of your timer in the various service events, like pause, stop, start.

Comment: Interesting. Of course, my WCF channel factory object is defined at Windows Service level. I agree for your suggestion without AutoReset, it's another way to handle it. But I don't understand why I'd need an Interlock handling as no parallel tasks can occur in my case?

Comment: I think that in this solution you have to use Interlocked because while you will read this flag, another thread able to write to it. If you have to write to memory in one thread and read it from another thread, you should use thread safe constructions. Interlocked is good to thread safe reading/writing to that flag.

Comment: Ok... And I've just thought that I may have concurrent memory accesses in OnStop() or OnSessionChanged() methods of my Windows Service for example... I've readen some darkness points concerning Interlock so I wanted to avoid them... :)

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is based on System.Threading.Timer and `Elapsed` occurs on a ThreadPool thread, so is not on the main thread. Hence the need for thread safety when using timers.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification DvS!